# how to make date() to return 00:00 in php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm using date() function after fetching data from database i'm feeding it into date() function.

it works for every other input but fails for 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in this case it returns 01:01(but i want 00:00)

here is my code :

```
<?php
$timestamp = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
echo date('d:m', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $timestamp)));
```

i want to display it inside `<title>` tag something like this

```
title="<?php echo @date('d:m', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $timestamp))); ?>"
```

**QUESTION:It is returning 01:01 for 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for others working fine how to make it to return 00:00(for 0000-00-00 00:00:00)** ?

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: you want to return 00:00 as day:month?

Comment: you need month or time
?

Comment: You should start with the manual.

Comment: @krasipenkov, yes  wat you said

Comment: hours means use `print date('H:i');`

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer, you should read the manual as i'm asking date('d:m')

Comment: "00:00" is an invalid day combined with an invalid month. no date function will return that. the above timestamp is a representation of `null` as datetime-string. i am curious as to why you get "01:01", i tried your code and get "30:11"

Comment: if you want to get day:month than its working fine... 01(Day):01(Month), logically, month or Day can't 00, in any calendar

Comment: @devpro,which one is working fine i din't get you. i'm using this inside title if direct solution will be better

Comment: `<title>00:00</title>` something like that?

Comment: @devpro, title="<?php echo @date('d:m', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $timestamp))); ?>"   something like that

Comment: you can check the given below answer you just need to use echo PArrt in title tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input date is invalid date so `date` function will not return wanted result.
But this will work:

```
<?php
$timestamp = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
$arr = explode(" ", $timestamp);
$arr = explode("-", $arr[0]);
echo $arr[1].':'.$arr[2];
```

or single line:

```
echo preg_replace('/(0000)-(00)-(00) (.+)/', '$2:$3', $timestamp);
```

or this one (it will work even with valid dates):

```
echo preg_replace('/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) (.+)/', '$2:$3', $timestamp);
```

Comment: i'm using inside title tag if you have direct solution then it is better

Comment: i'm expecting direct solution for this problem

Comment: What do you mean by direct solution?

Comment: inside title  tag any upto any ternary condition only not more than that

Comment: thanks for the answer your answer fits well for my scenario. sorry for the late